# Find function $f$ such that $(p*f)(x) = xf(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

**Question:**

> The function $p(x)$ is defined as $p(x) = e^{-x}$ for $x>0$ and $p(x) = 0$ for $x<0$.
>   Find the Fourier Transform of $p(x)$ and use the convolution theorem to find $f(x)$ such that:
>   $$\int_0^{\infty} p(y)f(x-y) dy = xf(x)$$

**My attempt:**

I have found $\hat{p}(k) = \frac{1}{1 + ik}$. I took the convolution of both sides and obtained the ODE $$\hat{f}(k) = i(1 + ik)\hat{f}'(k)$$ which I solved to yield $$\hat{f}(k) = \frac{1}{A(1 + ik)}$$ where $A$ is an arbitrary constant. After inverting this using the expression for $\hat{p}(k)$ earlier, and substituting into the original question, I get the left hand side integral diverging to infinity.

I cannot find my mistake and am unsure how to progress. Could someone please point me in the right direction?Thank you.

Comment: The way you solve the ODE in $\hat{f}(k)$ is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)* of the functional identity $(p*f)(x)=xf(x)$, we obtain $\widehat{p*f} =\widehat{\text{id}\, f}$, where $\text{id}\, f$ is the mapping $x \mapsto xf(x)$. According to the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem), we have
$$
\widehat{p*f}(\nu) = \hat{p}(\nu)\hat{f}(\nu) = \frac{\hat{f}(\nu)}{1+2\text i\pi \nu} .
$$
According to a property of the Fourier transform,
$\widehat{\text{id}\, f}(\nu) = \frac{\text i}{2\pi} \hat{f}' (\nu)$,
so that we end up with the differential equation
$$
\hat{f}'(\nu) +  \frac{2 \text i\pi}{1+2\text i\pi \nu} \hat{f}(\nu) = 0 .
$$
The solutions are $\hat{f}(\nu) = C/(1+2\text i\pi \nu)$, where $C$ is constant. The inverse Fourier transform is the function $f$ defined by
$$
f(x) = C e^{-x} u(x) = C p(x) ,
$$
where $u$ is the Heaviside unit step function.

---

*The convention used is $\hat{f}(\nu) = \int_{\Bbb R} f(x) e^{-2\text i \pi \nu x}\,\text d x$.

Comment: As $p(x)=u(x)e^{-x}$ you get $$p'(x)=\delta(x)-u(x)e^{-x}$$ resulting in $$(p'*f)(x)=f(x)-(p*f)(x)=(1-x)f(x).$$ The resulting differential equation is $$x(f'(x)+f(x))=0$$ with solutions $Cu(x)e^{-x}$. To verify, the convolution integral is $$\int_0^x e^{-y}e^{-(x-y)}dy = xu(x)e^{-x}$$ which satisfies the given equation. I'm not sure if one can justify the ramp factor $u(x)$ in the solution organically, except by reducing the admissible solution space to functions with $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$.

Comment: One can probably say that because of the factor $x$ in the ODE that it is not defined in $x=0$ and thus any solution has two parts, $f(x)=Ae^{-x}1_{x<0}+B1_{x=0}+Ce^{-x}1_{x>0}$. Then investigation of the original equation gives $A=B=0$.